# google cloud storage: access cloud storage and provide download link for users

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

In my developent server, i am able to use the blobkey to download a csv object.  The problem is that in production, the blobkey does not download anything (it returns a 404); presumably because the blobkey is inaccurate.  I think this is because googles deprecation of the blobstore and is no longer using blobkeys. This means i need to try and download from google storage bucket.  I am not sure how to do this; In development server, i would go to this endpoint to download `/data?key=<blob_key>` to download the blob object.

I can also download the csv object if i navigate to the bucket and ot the item and then click download.  Is there some minor adjustments i can make to get the download to occur? BI would appreciate if someone could point me to a particular direction.

Comment: Do your users authenticate to Google with Google credentials? If so, ACLs and/or IAM sound like the answer.  If you need to provide a URL for download on request, then maybe signed URLs ... https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Comment: hey Kolban, do you have some sample python code that you can link. I have trouble with the google documentation.

Comment: Its a big area ... but here are some docs on creating a signed URL from an app and the example is python.   https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually

Answer (score 0):

To download objects from your buckets in Cloud Storage depending on your preferences you can check the following code sample (Python):

```
from google.cloud import storage


def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"
    # source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"
    # destination_file_name = "local/path/to/file"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print(
        "Blob {} downloaded to {}.".format(
            source_blob_name, destination_file_name
        )
    )
```

Be sure that you are not using Python 2.7 anymore since it became deprecated and it is not supported anymore. If you have Python 2.7 please upgrade to Python 3.7.

Comment: sadly i am using python2.7; i have no control over when we migrate away from it. Would having python 2.7 be an issue.  I am also curious what i need to set `destination_file_name` as.

Comment: It explains in the comment since I suppose you want the the user to download it in their PC's. `# destination_file_name = "local/path/to/file"`